# IIS7.5 SSL Question, Safari users get a prompt of certificate to select

Tags: safari, ssl-certificate, iis-7.5

Does this error:

[image: Select certificate for Safari]
Has something to do with this: [Apple KB item](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1679)

[image: IIS7 setting]

Should I set it to ignore? is that it? or is that not recommended? I use the SSL for a registration/sign-up form,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, that does resolve this issue. Safari is the only browser which prompts the certificate selection. It isn't even required in IIS. Strict apple ppl :P but setting SSL client certificates to ignore does resolve it.

Comment: I recommend marking this as an answer as it solves the problem, confirmed in my case.