# Safari forces user to select client certificate even if it is optional

Tags: safari, ssl-certificate, safari-5, client-certificate

This question is loosely related to another one:
[IIS7.5 SSL Question, Safari users get a prompt of certificate to select](https://superuser.com/questions/231695/iis7-5-ssl-question-safari-users-get-a-prompt-of-certificate-to-select), but since it was asked more than a year ago I thought that there may be some changes done in Safari.

So, the problem I am facing is following: I have a SSL protected service hosted by Apache with `SSLVerifyClient optional` setting on. All browsers except Safari let me get to the service without having client certificate installed, whereas Safari stops navigation if I hit `cancel` button on certificate selection popup.[image]

I was wondering if there is some setting in Safari that would make it possible to get through certificate selection or it is how it is with Safari and there is no chance to workaround it. Disabling client certificates in Apache is out of the question.

I am using Safari 5.1.7 on Windows and Mac

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

This is still a problem at this time (October 2015) in the latest Safari 8.0.6/7 versions with no indication of it getting fixed.

The only way I can get Safari to work with `SSLVerifyClient optional` is to really lower the restriction on the ciphers by setting them to `SSLCipherSuite ALL`. Of course this has the unwanted effect that weak cyphers can be used so I do not recommend it.